# Is the relation on a singleton set an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

So I understand that for a relation on a set to be an equivalence relation, it must satisfy three axioms:

For all $x, y, z \in X$ and the relation $R$ on $X$,

1. $(x,x) \in R$
2. if $(x,y) \in R$ then $(y,x) \in R$
3. if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ then $(x,z) \in R$

So if you have a relation on a singleton for example $ \{0\} $
then that relation would be $\{(0,0)\}$

Therefore, the first axiom is obviously satisfied. **However would the rules for symmetry and transitivity be satisfied as well? Or do you need $x \ne y \ne z $?**

Comment: Yes, that relation is an equivalence relation.

Comment: The assertion "if you have a relation on a singleton $\{0\}$ then it is $\{(0,0)\}$" is incorrect: there are exactly two relations on a singleton, the full (which you describe) and the empty. The full is an equivalence relation, the empty is not.

Comment: Ok is the empty an equivalence or not? I am answering a question that asks if every relation on a singleton is an equivalence relation, I just assumed there was one

Comment: The empty relation is not an equivalence relation on a non-empty set  because it is not reflexive.

Comment: The empty relation is not an equivalence relation because it is not reflexive: being reflexive requires $0$ (the unique element of your singleton) to be in relation with itself, which it is not since no element is in relation with itself.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong and @Gro-Tsen is right. The empty one is not reflexive.

Comment: (On the other hand, the empty relation **over the empty set** is an equivalence relation, though a massively uninteresting one.  But it might be useful as an example to think about.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen My mistake was mixing it up with that one.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand. Just to clarify something, if you had a set, say {0, 1, 2} would the relation {(0,0)} still be an equivalence one even though not all of the elements in the set are included in the relation? EDIT: I think it wouldn't be but {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)} would be right?

Comment: No, this relation is not reflexive. But {(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)} is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Ah thanks, just edited my comment as you answered haha

Comment: $\{(0,0)\}$ is an equivalence relation **over** $\{0\}$. But $\{(0,0)\}$ is *not* an equivalence relation **over** $\{0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are satisfied for the relation you specified. (As pointed out in comments there is another relation though, the empty relation, that is not reflexive.) There is no assumption made that $x,y,z$ are distinct. Indeed, even if there is more than one element the implications also need to hold in the case where some or all of $x,y,z$ are equal.

In another direction, if you have no instance that fulfills the premise the implication is still true.

So, if you had a condition of say "unequal symmetry" saying: "if for $x \neq y$ we have $(x,y) \in R$ then $(y,x) \in R$" then your relation would also have this property.